# How to get WordNet synsets for forms of collocations?

Tags: python, wordnet

The web WordNet search seems to understand forms of collocations mapping to the same synset(s).  For example, "have a good time" maps to the synset have_a_ball.v.01 as shown here:
[image]

Likewise, using the web interface, the past tense form "had a good time" also maps to the synset have_a_ball.v.01:
[image]

However, I cannot seem to get the wn.synsets() call from Python to deliver the same results.  The simple Python script I'm using is below:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

print(wn.synsets("have_a_good_time"))
print(wn.synsets("have a good time"))
print(wn.synsets("had_a_good_time"))
print(wn.synsets("had a good time"))
```

Which outputs:

```
[Synset('have_a_ball.v.01')]
[]
[]
[]
```

Is there any way to automatically map different forms of a collocation (e.g. "had a good time" and "having a good time") to the same synset from Python?  I'm confused by the different behavior of the web interface from what I see from lines 3 and 5 of my simple script.